# want to value of matching id in left join select

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables in mysql 1 for users, 2 for questions and 3 for results.

I have written the below query.

```
SELECT q.id,qr.user_id 
FROM questions AS q 
    LEFT JOIN results AS r ON q.id=r.question_id 
        and r.user_id in (SELECT user_id FROM students)
```

If the answer not exists in the results for that question. I want the question and user id in the results.
Example

```
user
U1
U2
U3

question
A
B
C

result
A U1 YES
A U2 YES
A U3 YES
B U1 YES
B U2 YES
B U3 YES
C U2 YES
C U3 YES

Desired Output
A U1 YES
A U2 YES
A U3 YES
B U1 YES
B U2 YES
B U3 YES
**C U1 No**
C U2 YES
C U3 YES
```

please help.

Comment: please provide sample data and your expected output in table format

Comment: user
U1
U2
U3

question
A
B
C

result
A U1 YES
A U2 YES
A U3 YES
B U1 YES
B U2 YES
B U3 YES
C U2 YES
C U3 YES

Desired Output
A U1 YES
A U2 YES
A U3 YES
B U1 YES
B U2 YES
B U3 YES
C U1 No
C U2 YES
C U3 YES

Comment: this is not the right way you've to add it to your question

Comment: I have added the sample data in to the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT q.id,qr.user_id 
FROM results AS r 
    LEFT JOIN questions AS q ON r.question_id = q.id
    INNER JOIN students AS s ON r.user_id = s.user_id
```